# Solving Complex number 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given Z is not 1.

1 + z/1 - z is purely imaginary number if and in only |z| = 1

I need one more help. Thank you

Comment: Please show your efforts

Comment: Do you mean $$1+\frac{z}{1-z}$$?

Comment: It works for $(1+z)/(1-z)$.

Comment: It is (1+z)/(1-z). I want to show what I did but I cant upload a screen shot :(

Comment: I think I have to eliminate Imaginary number in denominator and I tried. But I couldn’t get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = a+bi$ and $z \ne 1$.

Then:

Then $\frac {1+z}{1-z}=\frac{ (a+1) +bi}{(1-a) - bi} =$

$\frac {[(a+1)+bi][(1-a)+bi]}{[(1-a)-bi][(1-a)+bi]}=$

$\frac {(a+1)(1-a) + (1-a)bi + (a+1)bi + b^2i^2}{(1-a)^2 -b^2i^2}=$

$\frac {(1-a^2) + 2bi - b^2}{1-2a+a^2 + b^2}=\frac{1-(a^2 + b^2)+2bi}{1-2a +(a^2 + b^2)}$.

> $|z|= 1;z\ne 1 \implies \frac {1+z}{1-z}$ is purely imaginary.

$|z| = |a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = 1$ so $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

So $\frac {1+z}{1-z}=\frac{1-(a^2 + b^2)+2bi}{1-2a +(a^2 + b^2)}=\frac {1-1+2bi}{2-2a}=\frac{bi}{2-2a} = \frac b{2-2a}i$ is purely imaginary

> $\frac {1+z}{1-z}; z\ne 1$ is purely imaginary $\implies |z|= 1$

$\frac {1+z}{1-z}=\frac{1-(a^2 + b^2)+2bi}{1-2a+a^2 + b^2}$

$=\frac {1-(a^2+b^2)}{1-2a+a^2 + b^2} + \frac {2b}{1-2a+a^2 + b^2}i$.

As this is purely imaginary we have $\frac {1-(a^2+b^2)}{1-2a+a^2 + b^2}=0$ or

$1-(a^2+b^2) = 0$ or

$a^2 + b^2 = 1$ or

$|z| =1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the expression

$$\frac{1+z}{1-z} = \frac{1+z}{1-z}\frac{1-\bar{z}}{1-\bar{z}}  =  \frac{1+z -\bar{z} - \bar{z} z}{1-z - \bar{z} + z \bar{z}}  = \frac{1+z -\bar{z} - |z|^2}{1-z - \bar{z} + |z|^2}$$

Suppose $z=a + ib$, then $z- \bar{z} = i 2b$ and $2 - (z+\bar{z})=2-2a$.

and $$\frac{1+z}{1-z} = \frac{1-|z|^ 2 +i 2b}{1+|z|^2-2a}$$.

That quantity is going to be purely imaginary if and only if $ 1=|z|^ 2$